# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_5

Tags: java

I am following https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37115_01/dev.1112/e27134/as_api.htm#AIDEV6370 and using sample code which mentioned there in doc. i.e AccessClient.

When i compile through eclipse, i get below error,.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_5
    at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.<init>(AccessClient.java:216)
    at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.createDefaultInstance(AccessClient.java:358)
    at JAccessClient.main(JAccessClient.java:14)
```

I have checked and modified

```
public static final String m_configLocation = "C:\\U01\\eclipse-workspace\\OamAuthenticationService";`
```

However, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java API documentation for the exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html) says:

```
public class NoSuchFieldError
extends IncompatibleClassChangeError

Thrown if an application tries to access or modify a specified field
of an object, and that object no longer has that field.

Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.
```

This tells you everything you need to know. Namely, that you're probably building your application with an out-of-date class. Try cleaning and rebuilding everything.